# Onchange event after AutoComplete is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fire a change event after auto complete.this change event will load a textbox with a name corresponding auto completes selected id. auto complete event is working perfectly but the change event is not responding.

```
<script>
    $('#CustomerSupplyId').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Purchase/GetSuggestion",
                data: { text: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                        return { label: profile.CustomerSupplyNm, value: profile.CustomerSupplyId, id: profile.CustomerSupplyId }
                    }
                    ))
                },
                change: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                        $("#textbox").val(profile.CustomerSupplyNm);
                    }))
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong here or what should i do?
if i do the success method like this

```
success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                        return { label: profile.CustomerSupplyNm, value: profile.CustomerSupplyId, id: profile.CustomerSupplyId },                                
                            $("#textbox").val(profile.CustomerSupplyNm)
                    }
                    ))
                }
```

the 'testbox' is loaded but the auto complete suggestion is despaired.But the 'textbox value is being changed for every keystroke which i don't want.

Comment: As far as I know `$.ajax` doesn't have change property. If you wanna do anything after autocomplete do it inside `success`.

Comment: pls take a look. i have edited my question

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the textbox value in response's callback before returning

```
$('#CustomerSupplyId').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Purchase/GetSuggestion",
            data: { text: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                    $("#textbox").val(profile.CustomerSupplyNm);
                    return { label: profile.CustomerSupplyNm, value: profile.CustomerSupplyId, id: profile.CustomerSupplyId }
                }))
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: but it does not change if i select a name from auto suggestion.which i must do

Comment: by adding
$('#CustomerSupplyId').change(function () {
                                $("#textbox").val(profile.CustomerSupplyNm)
                            })
it works perfectly.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no change attribute for jquery's .ajax() method,

check docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) .

you should listen events after ajax call has been completed like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Purchase/GetSuggestion",
            data: { text: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                    return { label: profile.CustomerSupplyNm, value: profile.CustomerSupplyId, id: profile.CustomerSupplyId }
                }
                ))
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                do your dom manipulation here
            }
        })
```

Comment: I did as you said
complete: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                            $("#textbox").val(profile.CustomerSupplyNm)
                        }))

but after doing this the autocomplete suggestions is not working and no change on the 'textbox' value

Comment: if i do the success method like this
` success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (profile) {
                            return { label: profile.CustomerSupplyNm, value: profile.CustomerSupplyId, id: profile.CustomerSupplyId },                                
                                $("#textbox").val(profile.CustomerSupplyNm)
                        }
                        ))
                    }`
the 'testbox' is loaded but the auto complete suggestion is despaired.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax doesn't have a property change. So adding change property doesn't help.

I think what you want to do is something like this.

```
...
.autocomplete({
    source: {
        ...
    }
    change: {
        // Do something ...
    }
})
...
```